# Postfix: Different TLS certificates for each hosted virtual mail domain

Tags: ssl, postfix, virtualhost

I have a single machine with a single Postfix instance which hosts different virtual mail domains.

Is it possible to configure Postfix such that is uses different TLS server certificates (with different domain names) based on the domain which the SMTP client has used to connect to the server?

I am looking for a feature similar to Apache's virtual hosting based on SNI (server name indication).

My (fictitious) DNS configuration looks like

```
host12345678.my-hoster.tld.   IN  A           203.0.113.1
1.113.0.203.in-addr.arpa.     IN  PTR         host12345678.my-hoster.tld.

mail.my-1st-domain.tld.       IN  CNAME       host12345678.my-hoster.tld.
my-1st-domain.tld.            IN  MX     10   mail.my-1st-domain.tld.

mail.my-2nd-domain.tld.       IN  CNAME       host12345678.my-hoster.tld.
my-2nd-domain.tld.            IN  MX     10   mail.my-2nd-domain.tld.
```

My (fictious) Postfix configuration looks like

```
myhostname              = host12345678.my-hoster.tld
mydomain                = host12345678.my-hoster.tld
myorigin                = $myhostname
mydestination           = $myhostname
virtual_mailbox_domains = my-1st-domain.tld my-2nd-domain.tld
virtual_mailbox_maps    = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-virtual-mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport       = lmtp:unix:/run/dovecot/dovecot-lmtp
```

How do I add different TLS certificates to Postfix such that it uses either `my-cert-chain-for-1st-domain.pem` or `my-cert-chain-for-2n-domain.pem` depending on whether the client has used `mail.my-1st-domain.tld` or `mail.my-2nd-domain.tld` to resolve 203.0.113.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>No. SMTP doesn't contain any mechanism for SNI.</strike>
As pointed out by Steffen Ulrich in comments, it is indeed possible to do this, as STARTTLS allows for SNI and [DANE(RFC7672)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7672) requires this.

Postfix supports this in recent versions, using the [`tls_server_sni_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#tls_server_sni_maps) configuration directive.

The mapping file is simply a file with domain names followed by one or more certificates for that domain.

<strike>Furthermore, you should use a certificate that matches your HELO / hostname, and this has to match forward / reverse DNS, so there's no easy way to make the HELO/EHLO match anything custom.</strike>

Nor does it matter, because no humans should ever have to relate to MX records; it's not relevant if the mailserver is `foo.example.org` or `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.`. But the certificate should match DNS name, and DNS name should have working reverse entry.

Comment: *"No. SMTP doesn't contain any mechanism for SNI."* - Traditional SMTP has no mechanism to distinguish different targets. But STARTTLS does not exclude the use of SNI. In fact, RFC 7672 (DANE) requires the client to use SNI - see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7672#section-8.1. Similar requirement is in RFC 8461 (MTA-STS) - see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8461.html#section-7.1. And starting with Postfix 3.4 there is actually support for SNI and different certificates per domain.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, interesting. I was not aware! I've updated to that effect now :)